# display issue with markers on google map

Tags: php, database, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I will admit first off that I am very new at this so I may not seem the brightest but I am essentially tying to get data from the database (preferably address locations) to show up with marker pins (or whatever they're called..). I found a link that would walk me through the process but when I did what the page told me to do, the data markers wouldn't display on the page where the map was. I'm guessing something went wrong with the html file displaying the data because when I sort the data to an xml file in one of the function pages, the xml data displays from the database..Here's the link. https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

I would greatly appreciate any help into understanding what I'm doing wrong.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Google Maps AJAX + mySQL/PHP Example</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  }
};

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the file that turns the data in the database into an xml file

```
require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php"); 

// Start XML file, create parent node

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$connection=mysql_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

// Set the active MySQL database

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
} 

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {  
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} 

header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
$node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
$newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
$newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);  
$newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
$newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
$newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
} 

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

here is the file that seems to have the issue

```
// Start XML file, create parent node
$doc = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $doc->create_element("markers");
$parnode = $doc->append_child($node);

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
$node = $doc->create_element("marker");
$newnode = $parnode->append_child($node);

$newnode->set_attribute("name", $row['name']);
$newnode->set_attribute("address", $row['address']);
$newnode->set_attribute("lat", $row['lat']);
$newnode->set_attribute("lng", $row['lng']);
$newnode->set_attribute("type", $row['type']);
}

$xmlfile = $doc->dump_mem();
echo $xmlfile;

?>
```

Thanks for any help or insight!

Comment: Is your XML valid? Can you provide the URL?

Comment: @noob123, try taking off the `@` from `mysql_fetch_assoc` and set your error_reporting to `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)` so you can see if you have any errors and report back ;-)

Comment: @Guy, I've updated the post again and I ran the third file in my browser and I got this error: Fatal error: "Call to undefined method DOMDocument::create_element() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\maps\phpsqlajax_genxml.php on line 6". So that's where the error is apparently.

Comment: yeah that's a `createElement` not `create_element` :-) also goes for `appendChild` and `setAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

Change `create_element, append_child and set_attribute` to `createElement, appendChild and setAttribute`

Remove `dump_mem` and change the `echo $xml` to `echo $xml->saveXml();`

That should fix things up.

Comment: Sorry for sounding like I'm not experienced but should I take out the line "$xmlfile = $doc->dump_mem();" or just the "dump_mem" part? A little confused on that since doc variable is going to the dump mem

Comment: after changing all of that, I get this error on this file: "This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it! I just needed to change my while loop to this: 
    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
    $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
    $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
    }
thanks for all your help!!